# How to replace a string in file on remote computer in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a VM running Windows Server 2012.And some intended services on it. I want to change a configuration file on this VM machine remotely from my desktop pc. 
Currently I change this configuration file by mapping the `C:` drive of the remote server and then changing the file. Now this blocks me from changing multiple servers as I can't map multiple server `c:` simultaneously to same drive. Also, mapping hundreds of drives wouldn't be ideal.
The way I am changing the file by mapping drive is:

```
$password = <password text> | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "admin"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
net use Z: \\$ipAddress\C$ <password> /user:admin type 'z:\Program Files\lalaland\Data\Settings.xml'

(Get-Content 'z:\Program Files\lalaland\Data\Settings.xml') | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $oldString, $newString } | Set-Content 'z:\Program Files\lalaland\Data\Settings.xml'
type 'z:\Program Files\lalaland\Data\Settings.xml'
net use z: /delete
```

Therefore I searched for a better option and found this script at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Replace-String-58fbfa85 but it doesn't work for me.

I am using this script as :

```
.\Replace-StringInFile.ps1 -ComputerName  <RemoteComputerHostName> -TargetPath 'C:\Program Files\lalaland\Data' -Fil
```

eName Settings.xml -Replace $oldString -ReplaceWith $newString -Credential (Get-Credential)

when I run the command credential window pops up asking for username and password. I enter the username and password that I used for mapping the drive, but it throws the following error:

```
New-PSSession : [<RemoteHostName>] Connecting to remote server <RemoteHostName> failed with the following error message : The user name or password is incorrect. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At D:\workspace\Replace-StringInFile.ps1:84 char:14
+ ...  $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Creden ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogonFailure,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

what I don't understand is when I map the drive with the same credentials it works fine but using the other script, which internally uses `New-PSSession` doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Editing the file via UNC path name (presuming administrator privilege, etc.) is by far the easist way.

Comment: you can create multiple powershell jobs that run your "one computer" version against each remote system. if that script has no problems running as you, then the jobs will have no problem. [*grin*] ///// i would likely use `Invoke-Command` to run the code on each system. that would save sending the file from the source to your system & then sending it back. the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet can accept a list of system names in the `-ComputerName` parameter. take a look at `Get-Help Invoke-Command` for more details.

Comment: Are the remote endpoints enabled for PSremoting? 
Anyway, is there a reason you aren't just using the admin share and UNC paths e.g.Get-Content '\\$ipaddress\c$\Program Files\lalaland\Data\Settings.xml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using the following cmdlet:

```
function Edit-RemoteFileStringReplace
{
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateScript({$_ -match [IPAddress]$_ })][string]$Address,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Replace,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ReplaceWith,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential
  )

  $DriveLetter=""
  $FilePathWithoutDriveLetter=""

  $DriveName = $Address.replace('.','x')
  $DriveName = "PSDrive_$DriveName"

  $DriveLetter = (Get-DriveLetterFromPath -Path $FilePath).Substring(0,1)
  $FilePathWithoutDriveLetter = Remove-DriveLetterFromPath -Path $FilePath
  $MappedFilePath="$DriveName" + ":$FilePathWithoutDriveLetter"

  New-PSDrive -Name $DriveName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$Address\$DriveLetter$ -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
  (Get-Content $MappedFilePath) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $Replace, $ReplaceWith } | Set-Content $MappedFilePath
  Remove-PSDrive -Name $DriveName
}
```